# What does it mean to get this message on EDAS?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission

I submitted two papers to a conference on [EDAS](https://edas.info). I checked EDAS and I saw a change. They added this sentence at the end of both papers page submission:

> "You have authored an accepted paper."

The results of the acceptance will be announced in 10 days, but I was wondering if I can take this as a sign of an accepted paper?
My advisor thinks otherwise, and he says we need to wait.

Thanks

Comment: What does the EDAS site say?

Comment: The official results will be out in 10 days. But when I check EDAS it says  "You have authored an accepted paper." @SolarMike

Comment: Let’s be clear - how do they explain their statements, do they provide more info elsewhere on their site...

Comment: @SolarMike No nothing. I think there is a probability that only one of my papers got accepted. I can't wait till the next 10 days. :(

Comment: @Jacob: And was it indeed an accepted paper?

Comment: @OnurA Yes. Check my answer below

Comment: @Jacob Are you aware of a case where this turns out to be a false positive?

Answer (score 8):

The answer is Yes!
Although, you need to be careful that it doesn't mean all of your papers are accepted (if you have submitted several papers). It means, at least one of your papers is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in EDAS and yes if you only had one paper, it means that it is accepted.